# Measuring great circle distance like length in cylindrical coordinate?

Tags: analytic-geometry, approximation, cylindrical-coordinates

[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wVFef.png)

Is there a formula to calculate "great circle distance" like length in cylindrical coordinate? As in the yellow line between 2 points in the attached picture.

I think I can interpolate and break this curved line between 2 points into small chunk then approximate using just euclidean distance but are there a better way to do this?

Comment: Your image is broken.

Comment: @AlexR Should work now

Comment: It says the image no longer exists. Please use the image button to add the image inline with your post.

Comment: Sorry about that.
There was an inline image in the first version of the post, which was removed by moderator for unknown reason. It is reposted as a link now. @AlexR.

Comment: Cylindrical coordinates are of the form $(\rho,\phi,z)$, so any circular distance is of the form $\rho \Delta\phi$. Does that answer your question?